# Clearing an array before a break in a for loop

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to flatten arrays of integers within arrays, throwing an error if an object in the array is not an integer. 
Below is my method:

```
def flattenArray(oldArray)
  result = [] 
  for i in oldArray do
    if i.is_a? Integer
      result.push(i)
    elsif i.is_a? Array
      result += flattenArray(i)
    else
      print("\nError: '#{i}', is invalid, only flattens arrays with type integer.")
      print("\n'#{i}' was not flattened with the array \n")
      # This doesn't work the way I expect
      return result.clear
      break
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

Here are some sample arrays to test:

```
sample1 = [1,[2,[3]],4]
sample2 = [1,['be',[3]],4]
sample3 = [sample1,[2,[3,4]],[5]]
sample4 = [sample1, [1.5, 3],4, [5,6],7,[[8]]]

flattenArray(sample1) # => [1, 2, 3, 4] (expected)
flattenArray(sample2) # => [1, 3, 4] (expected [])
flattenArray(sample3) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5] (expected)
flattenArray(sample4) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] (expected [])
```

The errors print fine, but when I try to make a break in my `else` statement and clear the array, it won't actually clear the array, instead it keeps the integers that were passed through before the error. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Any help pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: `break` is never executed because of the `return` right above it.

Comment: Result cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` only returns from the innermost recursive call.  If you want to abort processing the whole array, you need to detect that the result is empty and abort all the way up:

```
    elsif i.is_a? Array
      # this will just append [] if the recursive call aborts
      result += flattenArray(i) 
    else
```

Instead you want something like this:

```
    elsif i.is_a? Array
      subResult = flattenArray(i) 
      if subResult.empty? then
         return result.clear
      else
         result += subResult
      end
```

Of course, that will be a problem if you want to allow empty inner arrays.  Using empty arrays to signal an error condition is ambiguous as well as non-idiomatic in Ruby. It would be better to return `nil` or raise an exception.

```
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "Noninteger array element" 
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your result cannot be reproduced.

As for the reason an empty array is not returned when an error is raised is because `result` is different for each recursive call. For example, for `[1,['be',[3]],4]`, the array `['be',[3]]` causes an error, and you return an empty array for that part, but that does not make the entire return value an empty array. The entire array returned is `[1, 4]` (unlike what you claim), and the `['be',[3]]` part is mapped to nothing.